# how to modify a "<form>"variable from a webpage variable

Tags: wordpress

I have the following structure on wordpress:

```
<form method="post" action="https://gateway.payulatam.com/ppp-web-gateway/pb.zul" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <...>
  <input name="amount" type="hidden" value="5000.00"/>
  <...>
</form>
```

I need to change the value of the input name amount dinamically..

I have a variable that displays my price:

```
<span class="tourmaster-tour-booking-bar-total-price">$1,745,000</span>
```

But the "tourmaster-tour-booking-bar-total-price" changes in some web pages.

I want to read the "tourmaster-tour-booking-bar-total-price" variable and give this variable to the 'value' in my input amount.

Thank you very much!

I've been struggling with this. Please take a moment to help me, I'll appreciate

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily using jquery!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var formPrice = $('.tourmaster-tour-booking-bar-total-price').html().replace(/[$,]/g, '');
$('form #input-price').val(formPrice);
});
```

Comment: should I  add a <script></script> before </body>, right?? importing the Jquery library before </head>

Comment: Yes you can add the script tags before the closing body tag but it is good practice to place it in a seperate file such as "main.js" and [enqueue](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script) the file through you functions.php .
You can also do this for loading in jQuery.